# How to use two floats in navigation

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get a dropdownbar in my navigation which displays the elements vertically. The dropdownbar is already here and works fine but I'm having some trouble getting it to display vertically. Thanks in advance for taking a look, sorry if it's a rookie mistake!

I've already tried using floats, vertical-align, content-align.

```css
.nav {
  border-color: lightgray;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 54px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: dimgray;
  /* border-right: 1px solid dimgray; */
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray; */
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: dimgray;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #696969;
  color: #ffffff;
  pointer-events: none;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  display: flex;
  float: top;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-left: 1px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigatie" class="nav">
  <h1 class="outlineNaam">navigatie</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <li><a href="html/producten.html">Producten</a></li>
      <li><a href="html/personaliseren.html">Personaliseren</a></li>
      <li class="subnav"><a>Over ons</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="html/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="html/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U should use **flex-direction: column**:

```
ul li:hover > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* float: top; */
    vertical-align: top;
    border-left: 1px solid dimgray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray;
}
```

Also *float* property has no value "top":
[see on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)
 and the *float* property and *vertical-align* is ignored in a flex container.

*From the flexbox specification:*

[3. Flex Containers: the flex and inline-flex display values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)

> A flex container establishes a new flex formatting context for its
>   contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context,
>   except that flex layout is used instead of block layout.
>
> For example, floats do not intrude into the flex container, and the
>   flex container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its
>   contents.
>
> float and clear do not create floating or clearance of flex item, and
>   do not take it out-of-flow.

Comment: That did the trick, didn't even know that was a thing!
Thanks you so much for helping!

Comment: you're a lifesaver, hit me up if there is any way I could help you out :p !

Comment: is `float: top` a valid rule and does `vertical-align: top` affect the `.subnav` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll simply need to apply `flex-direction: column` to the `.subnav` (you did select it using `ul li:hover > ul`) which will make the `.subnav` elements align vertically as columns.

Also, there is not value of `top` for the `float` rule and the `vertical-align` doesn't affect `flex` elements.

So, here's a working demo :

```css
.nav {
  border-color: lightgray;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 54px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: dimgray;
  /* border-right: 1px solid dimgray; */
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray; */
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: dimgray;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #696969;
  color: #ffffff;
  pointer-events: none;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-left: 1px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid dimgray;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigatie" class="nav">
  <h1 class="outlineNaam">navigatie</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <li><a href="html/producten.html">Producten</a></li>
      <li><a href="html/personaliseren.html">Personaliseren</a></li>
      <li class="subnav"><a>Over ons</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="html/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="html/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: yeah i got the answer, but still i really appreciate you helping me out!
If there's a way I could help you out, feel free to hit me up !

Comment: I posted that answer so you could get the mistakes you did (like `flot: top` which is incorrect) even I knew you had the answer (even it has some errors).

Comment: alright, that's very kind of you! thanks for taking the time!
If i can ever help you out in anyway, let me know